# Finding radius of convergence of power series of $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ centered at $x=1$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series, taylor-expansion

> How can I find the radius of convergence of  power series of $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ centered at $x=1$ **without** using complex analysis?

My attempt so far:
$$\frac{1}{1+x^2} = \frac{1}{1+((x-1)+1)^2}= \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1+((x-1)+\frac{(x-1)^2}{2})}.$$We can expand this like $\frac{1}{1-x} = 1+x + x^2....$ if $-1 <(x-1)+\frac{(x-1)^2}{2} < 1 $ which gives $-\sqrt{3}<x<\sqrt{3}$ but we know that the radius of convergence for this particular series at x=1 is $\sqrt{2}$. How can i approach here?

Comment: This question is not particularly well-posed. What do you mean by the radius of convergence of $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$? This is an algebraic expression, neither a sequence nor a series, and hence there is not question of convergence.

Comment: Sorry, edited it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Complex Analysis it's really easy: it's the distance from $1$ to $\pm i$, which is $\sqrt2$.

Without it, it can be done as follows. If you compute the first terms of the Taylor series of $\frac1{x^2+1}$ centered at $1$, you will get\begin{multline}\frac{1}{2}-\frac{x-1}{2}+\frac{1}{4} (x-1)^2-\frac{1}{8}(x-1)^4+\frac{1}{8} (x-1)^5-\frac{1}{16} (x-1)^6+\\+\frac{1}{32}(x-1)^8-\frac{1}{32} (x-1)^9+\frac{1}{64}(x-1)^{10}-\frac{1}{128} (x-1)^{12}+\\+\frac{1}{128}(x-1)^{13}-\frac{1}{256}(x-1)^{14}+\frac{1}{512}(x-1)^{16}+O\left((x-1)^{17}\right).\end{multline}There is a pattern here: it looks as if this is the sum of $3$ power series:

- $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n(x-1)^{4n+2}}{4^{n+1}}\left(=\frac{(x-1)^2}4\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n(x-1)^{4n}}{4^n}\right)$;
- $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n(x-1)^{4n}}{2\times4^n}\left(=\frac12\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n(x-1)^{4n}}{4^n}\right)$;
- $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(x-1)^{4n+1}}{2\times4^n}\left(=-\frac{x-1}2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n(x-1)^{4n}}{4^n}\right)$.

These are geometric series, and it's easy to see that their sums are$$\frac{(x-1)^2}{(x-1)^4+4},\ \frac2{(x-1)^4+4}\text{ and }\frac{2(x-1)}{(x-1)^4+4}$$respectively. Since it turns out that the sum of these $3$ rational fractions is indeed $\frac1{x^2+1}$, then the pattern detected above is the correct one. It it is easy now the see that the radius of convergence of the power series that we got (which, as we have seen, is indeed the Taylor series of $\frac1{x^2+1}$ centered at $1$) is in fact $\sqrt2$.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think about splitting the Taylor expansion into 3 separate series!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.